# What is the CSS for repeating images in body

Tags: css

I want to achieve [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/526/designc.jpg/)

I am able to repeat images in container but can't figure out how to repeat in body in equal proportions of the div.

```
body {

}

div#container {
 width: 500px;

}

div#header {
width: 500px;
background: url(images/head.jpg) repeat-x;
}


div#content {
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
}


div#footer {
width: 500px;
background: url(images/footer.jpg) repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Comment: Do you have content in those divs? If not, you'll need to set a height on them.

Answer (score 2):

If I got your question right, this should be the solution. You shouldn't be

```
body {

    }


div#header-container{
  width:100%;
  background: url(images/head.jpg) repeat-x;
}


div#header {
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
}


div#content {
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
margin:0 auto;
}

div#footer-container{
  width:100%;
  background: url(images/footer.jpg) repeat-x;
}

div#footer {
width: 500px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Your html should be like this:

```
<div id="header-container">
  <div id="header"></div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="header"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer-container">
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```